# how to generate below list of week data using Excel or some other tool?

Tags: java, excel

The typical week  starts from August 29th - Sept 4th. (i.e. week is starting from Friday and ends on next Thursday). how can i get list of all Start Week Date (i.e Friday) and End Week Date (i.e. Thursday).

is this possible using Excel or some other tool?

Thanks
CP

Comment: Do you want it in Java, or do you want it in Excel? Also, how many weeks of date(s) do you want?

Comment: Either Java or Excel. All Weeks for the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter *any* date in **A1**

In **A2** enter:

```
=A1+(4-WEEKDAY(A1,2)+1)  this is the first Friday following the date in A1
```

In **A3** enter:

```
=A2+7  and copy down
```

For the week end dates in **B2** enter:

```
=A2+6  and copy down
```